# Mocha + Nodejs + Heroku .env file

Tags: node.js, heroku, mocha.js, heroku-postgres

I have a REST app written in NodeJS running on Heroku. I have my .env file setup for local development and works fine whenever I run foreman to serve my app locally. The app also runs fine when I deploy it to my heroku server.

I am trying to write unit tests for my app with Mocha/Supertest/should/assert. When I run my app through Mocha, it doesn't load up the .env file to get my environment variables – in my case, the URL for the PSQL database. As a result, all my tests that involve DB I/O timeout.

I've been scouring the Internet for a solution but I can't seem to find anything helpful.

Here is some sample code:

app.js:

```
var application_root = __dirname,
    express          = require("express"),
    port             = process.env.PORT || 4482;
    pg               = require('pg').native,
    client           = new pg.Client(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

// Connect To DB
client.connect();

(...)

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.send('PS API is running');
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('PS API is running');
});

(...)

// Read Users
app.get('/users', function (req,res) {
    user.readUsers(res,client);
});

(...)

// Launch server
console.log('Listening on port: '+ port);
app.listen(port);
module.exports = app;
```

userTest.js

```
var request = require('supertest');
var assert  = require('assert');
var app     = require('app.js');
var should  = require('should');

describe('Get /', function(){
    it('should respond OK',function(done){
        request(app)
        .get('/')
        .end(function(err, res){
          res.status.should.equal(200);
          done(err);
        });
    });
});

describe('Get /api', function(){
    it('should respond OK',function(done){
        request(app)
        .get('/api')
        .end(function(err, res){
          res.status.should.equal(200);
          done(err);
        });
    });
});

// Getting All Users
describe('Get /users', function(){
    it('should respond OK',function(done){
        request(app)
        .get('/users')
        .end(function(err, res){
          res.status.should.equal(200);
          done(err);
        });
    });
});
```

.env

```
== LOCAL DB ==
DATABASE_URL=MY_DB_URL
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD_URL=MY_DB_URL
PATH=bin:node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

And the output I get from running `mocha test`

```
Listening on port: 4482

  ․․Getting all users
․

  2 passing (2 seconds)
  1 failing

  1) Get /users should respond OK:
     Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded
      at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:165:14)
      at Timer.list.ontimeout (timers.js:101:19)
```

When I replace the `process.env.DATABASE_URL` with my hardcoded PSQL local URL, the tests all pass. So it's clear that the .env file is not being read by mocha.

I have also tried passing env vars to Mocha with little success. Does anyone know of a proper way to have Mocha read in my environment vars from the .env file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [foreman gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/foreman) (written by a Heroku engineer, to make it easy to use `.env` files and `Procfiles` in development as you would on Heroku production) has a command just for this purpose: `run`.

`foreman run npm test` <-- or however you trigger your tests.

Alternatively, on my current project here's what we do:

- we have a test.env file containing the environmental variables and values appropriate for testing, in Unix `export` format. So, yes, `export DATABASE_URL=MY_DB_URL`. The format is a bit different, but that's an annoyance we're OK with
- We have a Makefile containing the following directives:

```
-include test.env

test:
    npm test
```

When we want to run the tests for our project we just `make test`. Make will load up the `test.env` file, assign all the environmental variables, then run `npm test` for us.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure, but I don't think you can make mocha read your .env file. That appears to be specific to foreman. If your environment variable definitions are plain KEY=VALUE, then I believe something as simple as `env $(cat .env) mocha` would do. Otherwise, you may have to do some preprocessing first using sed/perl/etc.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the internet for days, following is something, that's working for me:

`> PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH env $(cat .env) mocha`

It is to be noted that `PATH=$(npm bin):$PATH` is used as my environment was not able to find `mocha`.